# Geocoding how to search for addresses only in the bounds area

Tags: php, laravel, geocoding

I'm trying to search for a street address using Google Maps API within a specific boundary area. For example, I want Google Maps to search only in Romania, within the boundaries of city - Iasi. I am using `php` to give a call to the API and I pass the parameters in the URL like this:

```
$address = urlencode($address.','.config('maps.state').','.config('maps.country'));
$geocode = file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='. $address . '&sensor=true&components=country:RO&key='. env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY'));
```

When i try to search for a street that doesn't exists(e.g. toy) it just gives me an random address outside the boundary area. I tried implementing it with html/javascript to see if i can get some success there too, but still it goes outside the boundary area. Is there any way i could implement this using a geoJson?

Answer (score 0):

From the Google Maps API documentation:

> In a Geocoding request, you can instruct the Geocoding service to
>   return results biased to a particular region by using the `region`
>   parameter. This parameter takes a [`ccTLD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Country_code_top-level_domains) (country code top-level
>   domain) argument specifying the region bias. Most ccTLD codes are
>   identical to ISO 3166-1 codes, with some notable exceptions.

So just add `&region=ro` to the url to add the country bias of Romania.

Comment: I tried this too. When I send a call with an invalid address (e.g. toy) from Romania, it returns me an address from Romania (timisoara) which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: That's the best the Google Maps API can do. There's nothing you can do about it